# .Net Core 3.0 Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi I had an html helper that I used before.
I want to use the same helper in .net core 3.0, but it gives an error.
I've never used a core before, so I'm doing a new project to find out.
I couldn't find the corresponding codes. Can you help me. Thanks in advance for help

```
  public static class HtmlHelperExt
    {
        public static string IsSelected(this HtmlHelper html, string controllers = "", string actions = "", string cssClass = "selected")
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = html.ViewContext;
            bool isChildAction = viewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.IsChildAction;

            if (isChildAction)
                viewContext = html.ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext;

            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = viewContext.RouteData.Values;
            string currentAction = routeValues["action"].ToString();
            string currentController = routeValues["controller"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actions))
                actions = currentAction;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllers))
                controllers = currentController;

            string[] acceptedActions = actions.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
            string[] acceptedControllers = controllers.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();

            return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
        }

        public static string ContentArea(this UrlHelper url, string path)
        {
            var modulName = url.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            string modulContentLoad = "";

            if (modulName != null)

            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulName.ToString()))
                    modulContentLoad = "Areas/" + modulName;

                if (path.StartsWith("~/"))
                    path = path.Remove(0, 2);

                if (path.StartsWith("/"))
                    path = path.Remove(0, 1);


                path = path.Replace("../", string.Empty);

                return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/" + modulContentLoad + "/" + path);
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

My screenshot and codes are below

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Can you please show us your `using`s?

Comment: What I really want to do is mark the screen on which screen I am. I solved the problem. I added running codes. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really want to do is mark the screen on which screen I am. I solved the problem. I added running codes.

[image]

net.core 3.0 used version

```
 public static class HtmlHelperExt
    {
        public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper html, string controllers = "", string actions = "", string cssClass = "selected")
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = html.ViewContext;
            bool isChildAction = viewContext.ClientValidationEnabled;

            if (isChildAction)
                viewContext = html.ViewContext;

            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = viewContext.RouteData.Values;
            string currentAction = routeValues["action"].ToString();
            string currentController = routeValues["controller"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(actions))
                actions = currentAction;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllers))
                controllers = currentController;

            string[] acceptedActions = actions.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
            string[] acceptedControllers = controllers.Trim().Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();

            return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
                cssClass : String.Empty;
        }

        public static string ContentArea(this UrlHelper url, string path)
        {
            var modulName = url.ActionContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
            string modulContentLoad = "";

            if (modulName != null)

            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulName.ToString()))
                    modulContentLoad = "Areas/" + modulName;

                if (path.StartsWith("~/"))
                    path = path.Remove(0, 2);

                if (path.StartsWith("/"))
                    path = path.Remove(0, 1);


                path = path.Replace("../", string.Empty);

                return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/" + modulContentLoad + "/" + path);
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I'm using this way on the razor side

```
  <li class="kt-menu__item @Html.IsSelected(controllers: "Home", actions: "Index", cssClass: " kt-menu__item--active")" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home",new { area = "" })" class="kt-menu__link ">
                    <span class="kt-menu__link-icon">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" class="kt-svg-icon">
                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <polygon points="0 0 24 0 24 24 0 24" />
                                <path d="M12.9336061,16.072447 L19.36,10.9564761 L19.5181585,10.8312381 C20.1676248,10.3169571 20.2772143,9.3735535 19.7629333,8.72408713 C19.6917232,8.63415859 19.6104327,8.55269514 19.5206557,8.48129411 L12.9336854,3.24257445 C12.3871201,2.80788259 11.6128799,2.80788259 11.0663146,3.24257445 L4.47482784,8.48488609 C3.82645598,9.00054628 3.71887192,9.94418071 4.23453211,10.5925526 C4.30500305,10.6811601 4.38527899,10.7615046 4.47382636,10.8320511 L4.63,10.9564761 L11.0659024,16.0730648 C11.6126744,16.5077525 12.3871218,16.5074963 12.9336061,16.072447 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
                                <path d="M11.0563554,18.6706981 L5.33593024,14.122919 C4.94553994,13.8125559 4.37746707,13.8774308 4.06710397,14.2678211 C4.06471678,14.2708238 4.06234874,14.2738418 4.06,14.2768747 L4.06,14.2768747 C3.75257288,14.6738539 3.82516916,15.244888 4.22214834,15.5523151 C4.22358765,15.5534297 4.2250303,15.55454 4.22647627,15.555646 L11.0872776,20.8031356 C11.6250734,21.2144692 12.371757,21.2145375 12.909628,20.8033023 L19.7677785,15.559828 C20.1693192,15.2528257 20.2459576,14.6784381 19.9389553,14.2768974 C19.9376429,14.2751809 19.9363245,14.2734691 19.935,14.2717619 L19.935,14.2717619 C19.6266937,13.8743807 19.0546209,13.8021712 18.6572397,14.1104775 C18.654352,14.112718 18.6514778,14.1149757 18.6486172,14.1172508 L12.9235044,18.6705218 C12.377022,19.1051477 11.6029199,19.1052208 11.0563554,18.6706981 Z" fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" />
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </span><span class="kt-menu__link-text">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the help text and select `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures` namespace.